# In which software do the professional game developers create 3D Model?

Tags: xna, c#, models

I am just thinking about beginning game development in xna c#. However, I don't know (and no tutorial teaches) how do professional game developers create a 3D Model/Scene. How can we create a realistic looking model and what is the hardware configuration needed in machine for using such a software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I have used blender to model 3D models for one of my projects however you have many choices such as 3ds max, maya, Rhino, Lightwave,cinema 4d,etc

Also for detailing you can use ZBrush3, Mudbox.

According to me 3ds max is what most Game developers use

for 3ds max

Must have: Quad core, with >4GB ram. Good video card.

Nice to have: very top end quad core, 16GB ram, 4870 VC or better.

As for hard drives, pick up a couple of 500GB or larger, and you may want to look into RAID, possibly.

For 32-bit Autodesk Maya 2012

Microsoft® Windows® 7 Professional, Microsoft® Windows Vista® Business (SP2), or Microsoft® Windows® XP Professional (SP3) operating systems
Windows: Intel® Pentium® 4, AMD Athlon™ processor with SSE3 instruction set support (or higher)
2 GB RAM
10 GB free hard drive space
Qualified hardware-accelerated OpenGL® graphics card
Three-button mouse with mouse driver software
DVD-ROM drive
HDD: IDE, SATA, SATA 2, SAS, SCSI
Microsoft Internet Explorer 7.0 or higher, Apple Safari, or Mozilla Firefox web browsers

CINEMA 4D R12 and BodyPaint 3D R12

Detailed system requirements : http://www.maxon.net/products/general-information/general-information/system-requirements.html

Answer (score 7):

Professionals use Autodesk [Maya](http://usa.autodesk.com/maya/) and Autodesk [3ds Max](http://usa.autodesk.com/3ds-max/). Many indie developers use [Blender](http://blender.org), which is free. The XNA content pipeline has great support for the FBX file format, which is supported by both Maya and 3ds Max with a [plugin](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=6837478&siteID=123112). Google turns up this [Blender extension](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.4/Py/Scripts/Export/FBX-XNA) to support the FBX file format, but I've never used it.

The web sites for these products will list minimum hardware requirements. They tend to require lots of memory and a modern graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

[3rd max](http://usa.autodesk.com/3ds-max/) is a professional 3d modelling tool, but it is only available at a high cost.

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/) is a free and open-source one.

This is 3ds max minimum requirements :

> Intel® Pentium® 4 1.4 GHz or equivalent AMD® processor with SSE2 technology*
>
> 2 GB RAM (4 GB recommended)
>
> 2 GB swap space (4 GB recommended)**
>
> 3 GB free hard drive space
>
> Direct3D® 10 technology, Direct3D 9, or OpenGL-capable graphics card† (256 MB or higher video card memory, 1 GB or higher recommended)
>
> Three-button mouse with mouse driver software
>
> DVD-ROM drive††
>
> Microsoft® Internet Explorer® 8.0 internet browser or higher or Mozilla® Firefox® 3.0
>
> internet browser or higher
>
> Internet connection for web downloads and Autodesk® Subscription-aware access